# definite integration of a trigonometric function with branch cut

Tags: definite-integrals, residue-calculus, trigonometric-integrals, singular-integrals

Can anyone give a clue how  the following integration can be solved by Residue theorem?
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\, d\theta\,\cos^{1-\nu} \theta = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma\left(1-\frac \nu 2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac 3 2 -\frac \nu 2\right)}$$

where $0<\nu<1$

My thought is that if I can solve the above via contour integration then it will be possible to solve the following type of integration which had been asked before: ([complicated integration involving exponential and trigonometric functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624599/complicated-integration-involving-exponential-and-trigonometric-functions))
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\, d\theta\,\cos^{1-\nu} \theta  \,e^{-\alpha \,sin^2\theta+\beta\,sin\theta}$$

Comment: Why do you want to use the residue theorem?  Just let $cos(\theta)=x^{1/2}$, recognize a Beta function integral, and use the relationship between Beta and Gamma.

Comment: Actually I am dealing with a problem whose link is given here:(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624599/complicated-integration-involving-exponential-and-trigonometric-functions). So my thought is that if  contour  integration using residue theorem for the problem  here is possible,  I can make some progress for other problem as well . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$\cos^{1-\nu}\theta = \left(\frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2}\right)^{1-\nu}$$

From here, you may try to use the Binomial theorem together with the Euler Gamma function.